# Selenium ChromeDriver Failed to Start

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying out Selenium 4.15, and this is the most basic example I'm trying out.

```
package base;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BaseTests {
    public void setUp(){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseTests test = new BaseTests();
        test.setUp();
    }
}
```

But it still gives me an error

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.`

I looked and looked, but not the error nor anything I found is giving me info on this.

Comment: How/where did you install the chromedriver?

Comment: @SiKing I'm relying on the relatively new Selenium Manager. 
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/

Comment: I think you need Selenium => 4.6 for that.

Comment: @pcalkins Yep. That's why I'm using the latest stable 4.15.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium WebdriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830523/selenium-webdrivermanager)

Comment: If the browser isn't launching, you might try setting the binary location using ChromeOptions: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
 options.setBinary(new File("/path/to/chrome"));
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: @pcalkins Ideally I would let selenium's built in manager handle that implicitly if no path is given. But yes, I will definetly use that as a fallback.

Comment: @SiKing Unfortunately not. It's just like I described to pcalkins above, I can use it as a fallback.

Comment: the manager should be writing some logs... maybe check those to see where the problem might be.  Are you seeing anything written to console in the IDE before the exception?

Comment: @pcalkins  That's all significant info besides the stack trace. I'll also say I tried downloading and using a chrome driver manually. It caused the exact same issue. At least now I know it's not an issue in the Selenium manager


`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver`


I wonder if it could be a bug in the latest chrome version causing this

Comment: I think that happens when Chromedriver can't open/find a free port on localhost.(?)

Comment: You might also try running the manager manually and see if it's able to update everything.  Should be in your build directory, called selenium-manager.exe

Answer (score 0):

Add a `System.setProperty` call to the current program to specify the path to the executable file of a browser driver:

```
package selenium1Basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BaseTests {
    public void setUp(){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        BaseTests test = new BaseTests();
        test.setUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can check and try to resolve the issue:

Check ChromeDriver Version:
Ensure that the version of ChromeDriver you are using is compatible with the version of Chrome installed on your machine. Selenium and Chrome Driver versions should be compatible. Download the latest ChromeDriver version from the official ChromeDriver website (`https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/`) and make sure it matches your Chrome browser version.

Check Chrome Browser Version:
Ensure that you are using a compatible version of the Chrome browser. Sometimes, an update to the browser can cause compatibility issues with the WebDriver. Make sure your Chrome browser is up-to-date.

Set System Property for ChromeDriver:
In your code, before initializing the WebDriver, set the system property for the ChromeDriver executable. Make sure the path to the ChromeDriver executable is correct. Update your setUp method like this:

```
public void setUp() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Check Browser Path:
Ensure that the Chrome browser is installed on your machine, and the path to the Chrome executable is included in the system's PATH environment variable.

Verify Firewall and Proxy Settings:
Sometimes, network issues, firewalls, or proxy settings can interfere with the WebDriver's ability to start a session. Ensure that your network allows connections to the necessary addresses, and check if there's any proxy configuration that might be causing the issue.